# Missing the OpenSSL lib?

Tags: ruby, homebrew, rbenv

I have been trying to install ruby 2.1.1 but when I run it in the terminal, this is what i get:

```
$rbenv install 2.1.1

Downloading yaml-0.1.6.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/5fe00cda18ca5daeb43762b80c38e06e
Installing yaml-0.1.6...
Installed yaml-0.1.6 to /Users/nthulanemakgato/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1

Downloading ruby-2.1.1.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/e57fdbb8ed56e70c43f39c79da1654b2
Installing ruby-2.1.1...

BUILD FAILED

Inspect or clean up the working tree at      /var/folders/tj/_bd6whds6lb7wtn2m8ylwx7h0000gp/T/ruby-build.20140427221824.34053
Results logged to /var/folders/tj/_bd6whds6lb7wtn2m8ylwx7h0000gp/T/ruby-       build.20140427221824.34053.log

Last 10 log lines:
                          io-console 0.4.2
                          json 1.8.1
                          minitest 4.7.5
                          psych 2.0.3
                          rake 10.1.0
                          rdoc 4.1.0
                          test-unit 2.1.1.0
installing rdoc:                    /Users/nthulanemakgato/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/share/ri/2.1.0/system
installing capi-docs:         /Users/nthulanemakgato/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/share/doc/ruby
The Ruby openssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?
```

So I went on Google, searched and tried a few things like:

```
$brew link openssl --force
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1f... Warning: Could not     link openssl.     Unlinking...
```

then i tried

```
$ brew update
error: unable to unlink old '.gitignore' (Permission denied) error: unable to create file     CODEOFCONDUCT.md (Permission denied) error: unable to unlink old 'CONTRIBUTING.md' (Permission     denied) error: unable to create file LICENSE.txt (Permission denied) error: unable to unlink     old 'README.md' (Permission denied) error: unable to unlink old 'SUPPORTERS.md' (Permission     denied) Checking out files: 100% (1995/1995), done. Error: Failure while executing: git pull -    q origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master

$ brew upgrade ruby-build 

Error: ruby-build not installed
```

and,

```
$brew install openssl

==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/openssl-  1.0.1g.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring openssl-1.0.1g.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
A CA file has been bootstrapped using certificates from the system
keychain. To add additional certificates, place .pem files in
  /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs

and run
  /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/c_rehash

This formula is keg-only, so it was not symlinked into /usr/local.

Mac OS X already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

The OpenSSL provided by OS X is too old for some software.

Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add to your
build variables:

LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include

Error: Failed to create: /usr/local/opt/openssl
Things that depend on openssl will probably not build.
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1g: 429 files, 15M
```

and lastly,

```
$sudo brew install openssl
Password:
Error: Cowardly refusing to `sudo brew install`
You can use brew with sudo, but only if the brew executable is owned by root.
However, this is both not recommended and completely unsupported so do so at
your own risk.
```

and a couple of other things like(which details I won't go into unless you think its necessary):

```
$CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl" rbenv install 2.1.1
$CFLAGS='-g -O2' RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl` rbenv     install 2.1.1
```

and both haven't worked.

I have installed xcode
 
I have an OS X 10.9.2.
Homebrew is installed.
 
OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013

I don't understand what's going on and I have been struggling with this for a long time, please help.
Let me know if there is more information that you need in order to help and i'll happily provide it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to this challenge in another site.

```
$rbenv install --patch 2.1.1
```

then

```
$curl https://gist.githubusercontent.com/andschwa/11334511/raw/563d5c2efb869cafb0c65404d12243822bba2817/ruby-2.1.1-readline.patch | rbenv install --patch 2.1.1
```

I got this information from this link:
https://schwartzmeyer.com/2014/04/26/building-ruby-2-0-0-and-2-1-1-on-os-x/