# Installing Rails on Mac OS fails with several errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, homebrew, rbenv

I am trying to install Rails on my Mac OS v10.10.4 system, and it fails when I run `brew install rbenv ruby-build`. The error is:

```
Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/etc/openssl
Warning: Bottle installation failed: building from source.
```

At the end of the process it says:

```
installing man3/d2i_SSL_SESSION.3ssl
i2d_SSL_SESSION.3ssl => d2i_SSL_SESSION.3ssl
installing man3/ssl.3ssl
Cannot create directory /usr/local/etc/openssl: Permission denied
```

Here is the complete log of all what I tried during this attempt:

```
Mac-213978b7b1793718b9:ROR developer$ brew install rbenv ruby-build
Warning: rbenv-0.4.0 already installed
==> Installing ruby-build dependency: openssl
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/openssl-1.0.2d_1.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring openssl-1.0.2d_1.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/etc/openssl
Warning: Bottle installation failed: building from source.
==> Downloading https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2d.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> perl ./Configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2d_1 --openssldir=/usr/local/etc/openssl no-ssl2 zlib-dynamic shared enable-cms darw
==> make depend
==> make
==> make test
==> make install MANDIR=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2d_1/share/man MANSUFFIX=ssl
installing man3/d2i_SSL_SESSION.3ssl
i2d_SSL_SESSION.3ssl => d2i_SSL_SESSION.3ssl
installing man3/ssl.3ssl
Cannot create directory /usr/local/etc/openssl: Permission denied
make: *** [install_sw] Error 13

READ THIS: https://git.io/brew-troubleshooting

These open issues may also help:
Installing Elixir fails due to OpenSSL errors. https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/33218
Mac-213978b7b1793718b9:ROR developer$ rbenv install --patch 2.1.1
rbenv: no such command `install`
Mac-406c8f4772a8:ROR developer$ rbenv instal --patch 2.1.1
rbenv: no such command `instal`
Mac-406c8f4772a8:ROR developer$ brew install --HEAD ruby-build
==> Installing ruby-build dependency: openssl
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/openssl-1.0.2d_1.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/openssl-1.0.2d_1.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring openssl-1.0.2d_1.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/etc/openssl
Warning: Bottle installation failed: building from source.
==> Downloading https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2d.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/openssl-1.0.2d.tar.gz
==> perl ./Configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2d_1 --openssldir=/usr/local/etc/openssl no-ssl2 zlib-dynamic shared enable-cms darw
==> make depend
==> make
brew install rbenv ruby-build==> make test
==> make install MANDIR=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2d_1/share/man MANSUFFIX=ssl
installing man3/d2i_SSL_SESSION.3ssl
i2d_SSL_SESSION.3ssl => d2i_SSL_SESSION.3ssl
installing man3/ssl.3ssl
Cannot create directory /usr/local/etc/openssl: Permission denied
make: *** [install_sw] Error 13

READ THIS: https://git.io/brew-troubleshooting

These open issues may also help:
Installing Elixir fails due to OpenSSL errors. https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/33218
Mac-213978b7b1793718b9:ROR developer$ brew install rbenv ruby-build
Warning: rbenv-0.4.0 already installed
==> Installing ruby-build dependency: openssl
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/openssl-1.0.2d_1.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/openssl-1.0.2d_1.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring openssl-1.0.2d_1.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/etc/openssl
Warning: Bottle installation failed: building from source.
==> Downloading https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2d.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/openssl-1.0.2d.tar.gz
==> perl ./Configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2d_1 --openssldir=/usr/local/etc/openssl no-ssl2 zlib-dynamic shared enable-cms darw
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 brew install rbenv ruby-build
Mac-213978b7b1793718b9:ROR developer$ curl https://gist.githubusercontent.com/andschwa/11334511/raw/563d5c2efb869cafb0c65404d12243822bba2817/ruby-2.1.1-readline.patch | rbenv install --patch 2.1.1
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0rbenv: no such command `install'
100  1713  100  1713    0     0   1499      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  1498
(23) Failed writing body
Mac-213978b7b1793718b9:ROR developer$
```

I have looked at the folllowing links so far:

- http://rubyonrails.org/download/
- [Installing gem or updating RubyGems fails with permissions error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607193/installing-gem-or-updating-rubygems-fails-with-permissions-error)
- https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/
- https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.10-yosemite
- [Missing the OpenSSL lib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23329406/missing-the-openssl-lib)

Comment: I finally used this tutorial https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.11-el-capitan and it worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run this command first

```
sudo chown -R <your username>:admin /usr/local
```

Replace `<your username>` with whatever your username on your mac is. So, in my case, I would run

```
sudo chown -R Adrian:admin /usr/local
```

Then try installing rbenv and ruby-build.

Your problem is most likely caused by the use of package installers (.pkg files) as they tend to create files as root in places where they shouldn't.

Note: you can find out your username by running `whoami`

Comment: See "[Are my permissions for /usr/local/ correct?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/1393)" which discusses this in a lot more detail. In particular, read the comments to the answers which reveal a lot of additional concerns.

Comment: @theTinMan I disagree with the answer there, because /usr/local isn't a system directory and isn't meant to have sensitive or protected data, but that's a good point. In order to preserve the permissions of /usr/local, homebrew should be installed to a different directory.

Answer (score 0):

I finally used this tutorial [Setup Ruby On Rails on
Mac OS X 10.11 El Capitan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0k8BW.png) after updating my mac to EI caption few months back and this worked.

Here is log from console it will explain all what happens. And how finally I got to run my first ruby application. There are several mistakes that I made which a beginner might will, but I finally nailed it. Here is how it looks.

[image]

```
rptwsthi:~ developer$ $ gcc
-bash: $: command not found
rptwsthi:~ developer$ gcc
2016-06-27 15:16:33.881 xcodebuild[2150:87788] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID ACA8656B-FEA8-4B6D-8E4A-93F4C95C362C for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Unity4XC.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2016-06-27 15:16:36.662 xcodebuild[2153:87846] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID ACA8656B-FEA8-4B6D-8E4A-93F4C95C362C for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Unity4XC.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
clang: error: no input files
rptwsthi:~ developer$ $ xcode-select -p
-bash: $: command not found
rptwsthi:~ developer$ xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
rptwsthi:~ developer$ gcd
-bash: gcd: command not found
rptwsthi:~ developer$ gcc
clang: error: no input files
rptwsthi:~ developer$ xcode-select --install
xcode-select: note: install requested for command line developer tools
rptwsthi:~ developer$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
rptwsthi:~ developer$ git --version
git version 2.6.3
rptwsthi:~ developer$ --l --global
-bash: --l: command not found
rptwsthi:~ developer$ -l --global
-bash: -l: command not found
rptwsthi:~ developer$ git config -l -global
error: did you mean `--global` (with two dashes ?)
rptwsthi:~ developer$ git config -l --global
filter.media.clean=git-media-clean %f
filter.media.smudge=git-media-smudge %f
user.name=rptwsthi
user.email=awasthi.arp@gmail.com
core.excludesfile=/Users/developer/.gitignore_global
difftool.sourcetree.cmd=opendiff "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
difftool.sourcetree.path=
mergetool.sourcetree.cmd=/Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/opendiff-w.sh "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" -ancestor "$BASE" -merge "$MERGED"
mergetool.sourcetree.trustexitcode=true
filter.hawser.clean=git hawser clean %f
filter.hawser.smudge=git hawser smudge %f
filter.hawser.required=true
color.ui=true
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge %f
filter.lfs.required=true
rptwsthi:~ developer$ brew
Example usage:
brew [info | home | options ] [FORMULA...]
brew install FORMULA...
brew uninstall FORMULA...
brew search [foo]
brew list [FORMULA...]
brew update
brew upgrade [--all | FORMULA...]
brew pin/unpin [FORMULA...]

Troubleshooting:
brew doctor
brew install -vd FORMULA
brew [--env | config]

Brewing:
brew create [URL [--no-fetch]]
brew edit [FORMULA...]
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Formula-Cookbook.md

Further help:
man brew
brew home
rptwsthi:~ developer$ brew install gpg
Warning: You are using OS X 10.11.
We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakage.

==> Downloading ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/gnupg/gnupg-1.4.19.tar.bz2

curl: (28) Connection time-out
Trying a mirror...
==> Downloading https://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/gnupg/gnupg-1.4.19.tar.bz2
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> ./configure --disable-silent-rules --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gnupg/1.4.19 --disable-asm
==> make
==> make check
==> make install
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink bin/gpg
Target /usr/local/bin/gpg
already exists. You may want to remove it:
rm '/usr/local/bin/gpg'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
brew link --overwrite gnupg

To list all files that would be deleted:
brew link --overwrite --dry-run gnupg

Possible conflicting files are:
/usr/local/bin/gpg -> /usr/local/MacGPG2/bin/gpg2
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/gnupg/1.4.19: 53 files, 5.4M, built in 9.9 minutes
rptwsthi:~ developer$
rptwsthi:~ developer$
[Restored 27-Jun-2016, 17:19:44]
Last login: Mon Jun 27 17:18:49 on console
Restored session: Mon Jun 27 16:56:08 IST 2016
rptwsthi:~ developer$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
cat: /Users/developer/.ssh/id_rsa.pub: No such file or directory
rptwsthi:~ developer$ git config --globle color.ui
error: unknown option `globle'
usage: git config [<options>]

Config file location
--global              use global config file
--system              use system config file
--local               use repository config file
-f, --file <file>     use given config file
--blob <blob-id>      read config from given blob object

Action
--get                 get value: name [value-regex]
--get-all             get all values: key [value-regex]
--get-regexp          get values for regexp: name-regex [value-regex]
--get-urlmatch        get value specific for the URL: section[.var] URL
--replace-all         replace all matching variables: name value [value_regex]
--add                 add a new variable: name value
--unset               remove a variable: name [value-regex]
--unset-all           remove all matches: name [value-regex]
--rename-section      rename section: old-name new-name
--remove-section      remove a section: name
-l, --list            list all
-e, --edit            open an editor
--get-color           find the color configured: slot [default]
--get-colorbool       find the color setting: slot [stdout-is-tty]

Type
--bool                value is "true" or "false"
--int                 value is decimal number
--bool-or-int         value is --bool or --int
--path                value is a path (file or directory name)

Other
-z, --null            terminate values with NUL byte
--name-only           show variable names only
--includes            respect include directives on lookup

rptwsthi:~ developer$ git config --globle color.ui true
error: unknown option `globle'
usage: git config [<options>]

Config file location
--global              use global config file
--system              use system config file
--local               use repository config file
-f, --file <file>     use given config file
--blob <blob-id>      read config from given blob object

Action
--get                 get value: name [value-regex]
--get-all             get all values: key [value-regex]
--get-regexp          get values for regexp: name-regex [value-regex]
--get-urlmatch        get value specific for the URL: section[.var] URL
--replace-all         replace all matching variables: name value [value_regex]
--add                 add a new variable: name value
--unset               remove a variable: name [value-regex]
--unset-all           remove all matches: name [value-regex]
--rename-section      rename section: old-name new-name
--remove-section      remove a section: name
-l, --list            list all
-e, --edit            open an editor
--get-color           find the color configured: slot [default]
--get-colorbool       find the color setting: slot [stdout-is-tty]

Type
--bool                value is "true" or "false"
--int                 value is decimal number
--bool-or-int         value is --bool or --int
--path                value is a path (file or directory name)

Other
-z, --null            terminate values with NUL byte
--name-only           show variable names only
--includes            respect include directives on lookup

rptwsthi:~ developer$ git config --global color.ui true
rptwsthi:~ developer$ git config --global user.name rptwsthi
rptwsthi:~ developer$ git config --global user.email awasthi.arp@gmail.com
rptwsthi:~ developer$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C awasthi.arp@gmail.com
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/developer/.ssh/id_rsa): RubyFile
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Saving key "RubyFile" failed: passphrase is too short (minimum four characters)
rptwsthi:~ developer$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C awasthi.arp@gmail.com
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/developer/.ssh/id_rsa): RubyGitRSA
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in RubyGitRSA.
Your public key has been saved in RubyGitRSA.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:xPvbSBQV+/jJjwbEe9Q/Vcy6Zr1BkkHGwXVi+Z5YU4Q awasthi.arp@gmail.com
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 2048]----+
|            *==Bo|
|       .   ..*E.*|
|        o ... o+o|
|       . . .o=o++|
|        S ...o*+=|
|         o  o+==+|
|          o  =+ +|
|         . +  .+ |
|          o ... .|
+----[SHA256]-----+
rptwsthi:~ developer$ cat -/.ssh/idrsa.pub
cat: illegal option -- /
usage: cat [-benstuv] [file ...]
rptwsthi:~ developer$ cat ~/.ssh/idrsa.pub
cat: /Users/developer/.ssh/idrsa.pub: No such file or directory
rptwsthi:~ developer$ cat ~/.ssh/RubRubyGitRSA.pub
cat: /Users/developer/.ssh/RubRubyGitRSA.pub: No such file or directory
rptwsthi:~ developer$ cat /.ssh/RubRubyGitRSA.pub
cat: /.ssh/RubRubyGitRSA.pub: No such file or directory
rptwsthi:~ developer$ cat RubRubyGitRSA.pub
cat: RubRubyGitRSA.pub: No such file or directory
rptwsthi:~ developer$ ls ~/.ssh/id_rsa
ls: /Users/developer/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
rptwsthi:~ developer$ cat RubyGitRSA
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

+XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
rptwsthi:~ developer$ cat RubyGitRSA.pub
ssh-rsa XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX awasthi.arp@gmail.com
rptwsthi:~ developer$ sst -T git@github.com
-bash: sst: command not found
rptwsthi:~ developer$ ssh -T git@github.com
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.120' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
rptwsthi:~ developer$ ssh -T git@github.com
Permission denied (publickey).
rptwsthi:~ developer$ heroku keys:add RubyGitRSA.pub
-bash: heroku: command not found
rptwsthi:~ developer$ add RubyGitRSA.pub
-bash: add: command not found
rptwsthi:~ developer$ ls ~/.ssh/id_rsa
ls: /Users/developer/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
rptwsthi:~ developer$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C awasthi.arp@gmail.com
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/developer/.ssh/id_rsa): Users/developer/.ssh/id_rsa
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Saving key "Users/developer/.ssh/id_rsa" failed: No such file or directory
rptwsthi:~ developer$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C awasthi.arp@gmail.com
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/developer/.ssh/id_rsa): /Users/developer/.ssh/id_rsa
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /Users/developer/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /Users/developer/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
XXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX awasthi.arp@gmail.com
The key's randomart image is:
+---[XXX XXXX]----+
|      ..Xx   .x+.|
|       *.=x  X+ .|
|      x +x.  x .+|
|       x.+.. ..=.|
|      x X.*.+ . +|
|     . +.= *.  ..|
|      +.=.=.. .  |
|      .= xx. .   |
|       .X  .     |
+----[XXXXXX]-----+
rptwsthi:~ developer$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
ssh-rsaXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX awasthi.arp@gmail.com
rptwsthi:~ developer$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi rptwsthi! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
rptwsthi:~ developer$ gem install rails -v 4.2.6
Fetching: i18n-0.7.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed i18n-0.7.0
Fetching: thread_safe-0.3.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed thread_safe-0.3.5
Fetching: tzinfo-1.2.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed tzinfo-1.2.2
Fetching: activesupport-4.2.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activesupport-4.2.6
Fetching: rack-1.6.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rack-1.6.4
Fetching: rack-test-0.6.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rack-test-0.6.3
Fetching: mini_portile2-2.1.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mini_portile2-2.1.0
Fetching: pkg-config-1.1.7.gem (100%)
Successfully installed pkg-config-1.1.7
Fetching: nokogiri-1.6.8.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed nokogiri-1.6.8
Fetching: loofah-2.0.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed loofah-2.0.3
Fetching: rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.3
Fetching: rails-deprecated_sanitizer-1.0.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rails-deprecated_sanitizer-1.0.3
Fetching: rails-dom-testing-1.0.7.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rails-dom-testing-1.0.7
Fetching: builder-3.2.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed builder-3.2.2
Fetching: erubis-2.7.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed erubis-2.7.0
Fetching: actionview-4.2.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed actionview-4.2.6
Fetching: actionpack-4.2.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed actionpack-4.2.6
Fetching: activemodel-4.2.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activemodel-4.2.6
Fetching: arel-6.0.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed arel-6.0.3
Fetching: activerecord-4.2.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activerecord-4.2.6
Fetching: globalid-0.3.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed globalid-0.3.6
Fetching: activejob-4.2.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activejob-4.2.6
Fetching: mime-types-data-3.2016.0521.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mime-types-data-3.2016.0521
Fetching: mime-types-3.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mime-types-3.1
Fetching: mail-2.6.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mail-2.6.4
Fetching: actionmailer-4.2.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed actionmailer-4.2.6
Fetching: thor-0.19.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed thor-0.19.1
Fetching: railties-4.2.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed railties-4.2.6
Fetching: bundler-1.12.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.12.5
Fetching: concurrent-ruby-1.0.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed concurrent-ruby-1.0.2
Fetching: sprockets-3.6.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed sprockets-3.6.2
Fetching: sprockets-rails-3.0.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed sprockets-rails-3.0.4
Fetching: rails-4.2.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rails-4.2.6
Parsing documentation for i18n-0.7.0
Installing ri documentation for i18n-0.7.0
Parsing documentation for thread_safe-0.3.5
Installing ri documentation for thread_safe-0.3.5
Parsing documentation for tzinfo-1.2.2
Installing ri documentation for tzinfo-1.2.2
Parsing documentation for activesupport-4.2.6
Installing ri documentation for activesupport-4.2.6
Parsing documentation for rack-1.6.4
Installing ri documentation for rack-1.6.4
Parsing documentation for rack-test-0.6.3
Installing ri documentation for rack-test-0.6.3
Parsing documentation for mini_portile2-2.1.0
Installing ri documentation for mini_portile2-2.1.0
Parsing documentation for pkg-config-1.1.7
Installing ri documentation for pkg-config-1.1.7
Parsing documentation for nokogiri-1.6.8
Installing ri documentation for nokogiri-1.6.8
Parsing documentation for loofah-2.0.3
Installing ri documentation for loofah-2.0.3
Parsing documentation for rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.3
Installing ri documentation for rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.3
Parsing documentation for rails-deprecated_sanitizer-1.0.3
Installing ri documentation for rails-deprecated_sanitizer-1.0.3
Parsing documentation for rails-dom-testing-1.0.7
Installing ri documentation for rails-dom-testing-1.0.7
Parsing documentation for builder-3.2.2
Installing ri documentation for builder-3.2.2
Parsing documentation for erubis-2.7.0
Installing ri documentation for erubis-2.7.0
Parsing documentation for actionview-4.2.6
Installing ri documentation for actionview-4.2.6
Parsing documentation for actionpack-4.2.6
Installing ri documentation for actionpack-4.2.6
Parsing documentation for activemodel-4.2.6
Installing ri documentation for activemodel-4.2.6
Parsing documentation for arel-6.0.3
Installing ri documentation for arel-6.0.3
Parsing documentation for activerecord-4.2.6
Installing ri documentation for activerecord-4.2.6
Parsing documentation for globalid-0.3.6
Installing ri documentation for globalid-0.3.6
Parsing documentation for activejob-4.2.6
Installing ri documentation for activejob-4.2.6
Parsing documentation for mime-types-data-3.2016.0521
Installing ri documentation for mime-types-data-3.2016.0521
Parsing documentation for mime-types-3.1
Installing ri documentation for mime-types-3.1
Parsing documentation for mail-2.6.4
Installing ri documentation for mail-2.6.4
Parsing documentation for actionmailer-4.2.6
Installing ri documentation for actionmailer-4.2.6
Parsing documentation for thor-0.19.1
Installing ri documentation for thor-0.19.1
Parsing documentation for railties-4.2.6
Installing ri documentation for railties-4.2.6
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.12.5
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.12.5
Parsing documentation for concurrent-ruby-1.0.2
Installing ri documentation for concurrent-ruby-1.0.2
Parsing documentation for sprockets-3.6.2
Installing ri documentation for sprockets-3.6.2
Parsing documentation for sprockets-rails-3.0.4
Installing ri documentation for sprockets-rails-3.0.4
Parsing documentation for rails-4.2.6
Installing ri documentation for rails-4.2.6
Done installing documentation for i18n, thread_safe, tzinfo, activesupport, rack, rack-test, mini_portile2, pkg-config, nokogiri, loofah, rails-html-sanitizer, rails-deprecated_sanitizer, rails-dom-testing, builder, erubis, actionview, actionpack, activemodel, arel, activerecord, globalid, activejob, mime-types-data, mime-types, mail, actionmailer, thor, railties, bundler, concurrent-ruby, sprockets, sprockets-rails, rails after 393 seconds
33 gems installed
rptwsthi:~ developer$ rbenv rehash
rptwsthi:~ developer$ rails -v
Rails 4.2.6

cd HelloWorldFetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Resolving dependencies.....
Using rake 11.2.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
Using minitest 5.9.0
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.1.0
Using pkg-config 1.1.7
Using rack 1.6.4
Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
Using arel 6.0.3
Using debug_inspector 0.0.2
Using bundler 1.12.5
Using byebug 9.0.5
Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
Using multi_json 1.12.1
Using sass 3.4.22
Using tilt 2.0.5
Using spring 1.7.1
Using sqlite3 1.3.11
Using rdoc 4.2.2
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using nokogiri 1.6.8
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using mime-types 3.1
Using binding_of_caller 0.7.2
Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
Installing uglifier 3.0.0
Using sprockets 3.6.2
Installing sdoc 0.4.1
Using activesupport 4.2.6
Using loofah 2.0.3
Using mail 2.6.4
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
Using globalid 0.3.6
Using activemodel 4.2.6
Installing jbuilder 2.5.0
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
Using activejob 4.2.6
Using activerecord 4.2.6
Using actionview 4.2.6
Using actionpack 4.2.6
Using actionmailer 4.2.6
Using railties 4.2.6
Using sprockets-rails 3.0.4
Installing coffee-rails 4.1.1
Installing jquery-rails 4.1.1
Using rails 4.2.6
Installing sass-rails 5.0.4
Installing web-console 2.3.0
Installing turbolinks 2.5.3
Bundle complete! 12 Gemfile dependencies, 56 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
run  bundle exec spring binstub --all

* bin/rake: spring inserted
* bin/rails: spring inserted
rptwsthi:~ developer$
rptwsthi:~ developer$
rptwsthi:~ developer$
rptwsthi:~ developer$ cd HelloWorld
rptwsthi:HelloWorld developer$ rake db:create
rptwsthi:HelloWorld developer$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.6 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2016-06-27 21:08:36] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2016-06-27 21:08:36] INFO  ruby 2.3.1 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-darwin15]
[2016-06-27 21:08:37] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=37160 port=3000


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-06-27 21:08:56 +0530
Processing by Rails::WelcomeController#index as HTML
Rendered /Users/developer/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb (12.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 139ms (Views: 110.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/rails/info/properties" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-06-27 21:09:22 +0530
Processing by Rails::InfoController#properties as */*
                                                    Rendered /Users/developer/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/templates/rails/info/properties.html.erb (0.6ms)
                                                    Completed 200 OK in 117ms (Views: 53.6ms | ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

If a home brew install is causing problems your first reflex should be to run

```
brew doctor
```

This should diagnose most issues and even suggest remedies (such as the ones mentioned by other answers)