# Trouble installing Ruby (Failed to download resource "readline--patch")

Tags: ruby, download, installation, http-status-code-404, homebrew

I'm getting this error when I try to install Ruby. I've tried looking at [this](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/526) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31777019/installing-rails-on-mac-os-fails-with-several-errors) but to no avail

[image]

```
➜  ~ brew install ruby
Warning: You are using OS X 10.12.
We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
Please create pull-requests instead of filing issues.
==> Installing dependencies for ruby: readline, libyaml, makedepend
==> Installing ruby dependency: readline
==> Downloading https://ftpmirror.gnu.org/readline/readline-6.3.tar.gz
==> Downloading from http://mirror.team-cymru.org/gnu/readline/readline-6.3.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jacknagel/d886531fb6623b60b2af/

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Error: Failed to download resource "readline--patch"
Download failed: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jacknagel/d886531fb6623b60b2af/raw/746fc543e56bc37a26ccf05d2946a45176b0894e/readline-6.3.8.diff
```

Comment: Please post plain text errors as plain text in the body of your question. Images are often difficult for people to deal with: The text within them can't be copy-pasted into an answer or used for testing.

Comment: getting the same issue with python3 install

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've met the same problems when I installed Ruby on my Mac. Maybe you could try the following steps to solve this problem, it works for me :)

1. update your brew, paste `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"` at a Terminal prompt. (or following instructions on [brew](http://brew.sh/) homepage) Or just `brew update`
2. Run `brew install ruby`

Good luck to you! :)

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me! I executed the first step and then `rvm install 2.3.3`.